# Delimiter in different math font

Tags: stix, overbrace

Good day, Here we are using STIXMath-Regular for math font as per customer requirement, in STIXmath-Regular font over brace is clash with text, for alternate we plan to use STIXMathTwo font for over brace. Please suggest how to map over brace for this font.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\usepackage{unicode-math}%
\usepackage{multirow}

\setmathfont{STIXMath-Regular}

\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{l}
\textrm{E}=\left \{\begin{array}{l@{}}
{\overbrace{{laafkj}}^{2}},\, {\overbrace{{11-31}}^{2}} {\overbrace{{1-3}}^{2}} {\overbrace{{1-3}}} {\overbrace{{R}}} {\overbrace{{RH}}^{2}} \end{array}\right \}\\
\end{array}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why are you encasing almost every subformula in unneeded extra pairs of curyl braces? And what's with the two nested `array` environments? They don't seem to serve a discernible purpose.

Comment: Please do tell us which TeX distribution you employ and what the version of XeTeX is that's installed on your system.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: `\setmathfont[range=\overbrace]{Stix Two Math}`.

Longer answer: The real customer requirement is XITS Math, which has the glyphs from STIX Math Regular, but a working math table, scripts and other OpenType features.  STIX Math Regular doesn’t even work as the main math font any more with `unicode-math` v0.81.  You can thank Khaled Hosny for XITS and many other great fonts.

I can’t reproduce your bug with `\overbrace` on TeX Live 2018, but I got a different one.  (@egreg could in TeX Live 2016.)  If you want to replace the overbrace because it clashes with your text font, that’s likely an XY problem.  Here’s the solution you requested, anyway.  Delete the line `\setmathfont[range=\overbrace]{Stix Two Math}` if you want to use a single math font.

I took the liberty of changing the main text font to the matching STIX family, and changing `\textrm` within equations to `\symup` so that upright math symbols will be properly set in the math font.

Finally, I removed all packages not used in this MWE and some unnecessary pairs of braces.  I left in the nested `\array` environments for the sake of this example, but it’s not how I would write that code.

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{STIX-Regular}[
  BoldFont=STIX-Bold,
  ItalicFont=STIX-Italic,
  BoldItalicFont=STIX-Bold Italic,
  Ligatures={Common, TeX}]
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchUppercase}

\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[range=\overbrace]{STIX Two Math}

\begin{document}

\normalfont{STIX Regular E}
{\fontspec{Latin Modern Roman}Latin Modern Roman E}

\( \begin{array}{l}
\symup{E}=\left\{ \begin{array}{l@{}}
  \overbrace{laafkj}^{2},\,
  \overbrace{11-31}^{2}
  \overbrace{1-3}^{2}
  \overbrace{1-3}
  \overbrace{R}
  \overbrace{RH}^{2}
  \end{array} \right\}
\end{array} \)

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample]

Comment: I can only reproduce the OP's issue with TeX Live 2016; with later releases, the call for STIXMath-Regular is silently ignored.

Comment: @Davislor thanks for your answer, which has helpful for me.

Comment: @RajeshKumar Glad to help. Please consider accepting it. :)

Comment: Yeah! I accepting it, one more clarification is required, If I used "STIX Two Math" after "STIX Math". All the other symbols getting changed into "STIX two math". I want overbrace only in "stix two math". Please suggest how to resolve this. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @RajeshKumar I can’t reproduce your issue in TeX Live 2018. My recommendation is that you’re solving the wrong problem here. Change your math font to XITS Math, upgrade your TeX distribution, and you will be able to use the symbols your client requested instead of substituting `\overbrace`.

Comment: @RajeshKumar If, however, you really do want to solve problem Y and not problem X, you might try `\setmathfont[range="23de]{STIX Two Math}` instead of `\setmathfont[range=\overbrace]{STIX Two Math}`.

Comment: @RajeshKumar Sorry to bug you, but since you mentioned you were accepting it a day ago, you’re new here, and you don’t appear to have accepted an answer to any of your questions yet: are you aware that accept is the green check mark, different from upvote? The asker’s supposed to give that out. :)